# Bijection/Function Composition

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i'm working on this question here but don't exactly know how I am supposed to answer this.

"Let f and g be two functions. Prove that if f and g are both surjective, f ◦ g is also surjective."

Am I supposed to assume $f: A ⇒ B$ and $g: A ⇒ B$?

From here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are both $A \rightarrow B$, then $f ◦ g$ makes no sense.

Comment: Choose a x in the co-domain of f ◦ g.  If f is surjective, it maps to a point in the domain of f, which is also in the co-domain of g.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In order for $f\circ g$ to make sense, you must have the image of $g$ contained in the domain of $f$. So you should assume
$g:A\longrightarrow B$
and 
$f:B\longrightarrow C$, so that $f\circ g : A\longrightarrow C$.

This is sometimes written $A \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow}B\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}C$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $f: A ⟶ B$ and $g: B ⟶ C$, so that $f o g: A ⟶ C$?

Comment: No, what I wrote was correct. For $f\circ g$, you evaluate $g$ first, then $f$ (recall "$f\circ g$" is read "$f$ following $g$"). The composition you mention in the comment above would be the map $g\circ f: A\to C$. IN other words, $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$, and $(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification.